# every complex number can be put in this form?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am reading a proof of a theorem and I see this:

"if we put $F(x)$ in this form:
$F(x)= r e^{i\theta}$"

$F(x)$ takes values in $\mathbb{C}$, so the question is:

In $\mathbb{C}$, every element can be put in that form?

Comment: It is something like polar system?  where $r$ is the modul and $e^{i \theta}$ is the angle?

Comment: Yes, exactly.${}$

Comment: Yes. for any complex number, $x, y\in\Bbb R\not\{0\},\; z=x+iy$ we have $r=|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = \text{arg} z$ arg can be computed using arctangent.

Comment: Yes, but not uniquely represented in this way. Even if you ignore the $2\pi$ periodicity of $\theta$, there's still the ambiguity when $z=0$ because $0=0e^{i\theta}$ for all $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

It holds: $x=|x|e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta:= arcsin(\Im(x) /|x|) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ or something like that.

Comment: It depends on the argument of the function, I think that is correct